# Connect to Redis using java code if there is docker compose of Redis and Redis Commander

Tags: java, docker-compose, redis, jedis, redis-server

I am trying to connect to Redis using below Java code with Jedis library but connection is failng can someonen please help on this ?.

```
Jedis jedis = new Jedis("localhost");
String pingResponse = jedis.ping();
System.out.println("ping should return pong" + pingResponse);
```

and this is my docker-compose file

```
version: '3'
services:
  redis:
    container_name: redis
    hostname: redis
    image: redis

  redis-commander:
    container_name: redis-commander
    hostname: redis-commander
    image: rediscommander/redis-commander:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
    - REDIS_HOSTS=local:redis:6379
    ports:
    - "8082:8081"
```

below is the exception I am getting :

```
Exception in thread "main" redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Failed connecting to host redis:6379
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:204)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:100)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.sendCommand(Connection.java:125)
    at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.sendCommand(Connection.java:120)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.ping(BinaryClient.java:113)
    at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryJedis.ping(BinaryJedis.java:188)
    at com.altimetrik.demo.bean.Sample.main(Sample.java:23)
```

Comment: why is it failing? please post the exception and relevant logs.

Comment: @TomElias added error logs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think your Redis container does not expose ports outside for connection, only the commander exposes 8002. (try connecting to localhost:8002). docker compose creates a default "bridge" network so the containers can talk between themselves, but not outside unless you expose ports. the commander can connect to REDIS since they are on the same network.